# How to set subnet for Docker 1.9 overflow network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I try to setup Docker 1.9 by offical documents to make a overlay network,it take some error message like this:

```
root@c0-master:~# docker run -d --name webtest --net myStack3 nginx
a5aec996da782669bc26e5c33064bf6c14ee452a56b1a519136d47c2b9d59859
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container  a5aec996da782669bc26e5c33064bf6c14ee452a56b1a519136d47c2b9d59859: subnet sandbox join failed for "10.0.2.0/24": vxlan interface creation failed for subnet "10.0.2.0/24": failed in prefunc: failed to set namespace on link "vxlan48c4dd7": invalid argument
```

Docker network just show these simple message:

```
root@c0-master:~# docker network
docker: "network" requires a minimum of 1 argument.
See 'docker network --help'.

Usage:  docker network [OPTIONS] COMMAND [OPTIONS]

Commands:
  disconnect               Disconnect container from a network
  inspect                  Display detailed network information
  ls                       List all networks
  rm                       Remove a network
  create                   Create a network
  connect                  Connect container to a network

Run 'docker network COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

I remenbered when I use flannel to setup overlay network,it had etcd file and flannel file to point out the range of subnet.

I think this error cause of it.

How to set it by docker1.9&swarm?

Comment: This issue on the docker repo may help: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15772